# Appending data to json and getting it back as a map GOLANG

Tags: json, go

I'm quite new to json and GO, I want to create a key and value based json file, which will  append the data in key and value format, later will export it as a map(key and value), the data will save inside the `db.json` for later, to find the key value.
this is what I have:

```
type DATA struct{
    Key string 
    Value string 
}

func writeToDB(key, value string) bool  {


    var jsonText = []byte(`[
        Key:"", Value:""
    ]`)
    var indent []DATA
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonText), &indent)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    indent = append(indent, DATA{Key:key, Value: value})


    result, error := json.Marshal(indent)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    f, erro := os.OpenFile("db.json", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if erro != nil {
        fmt.Println(erro)
    }

    n, err := io.WriteString(f, string(result))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(n, err)
    }
    return true
}
```

the output of the file is like:

```
[{"Key":"k1ey","Value":"val1ue"}][{"Key":"k133ey","Value":"val1ue"}]
```

but I want something like:

```
{
   key:value
   key:value
   key:value
}
```

I can't get it right, I read many articles, but GO doesn't have an simple json integration

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert an array of objects to a map, here is a basic example:

```
func saveDbAsMap(db []DATA) {
    // Initialize a string map
    var dbAsMap = make(map[string]interface{})

    // Convert array of objects to map
    for i := 0; i < len(db); i++ {
        entry := db[i]
        dbAsMap[entry.Key] = entry.Value
    }

    // Marshal it to JSON
    dbAsMapBytes, error := json.Marshal(dbAsMap)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }

    // Write it to file
    error = os.WriteFile("db.json", dbAsMapBytes, 0644)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }
}
```

For testing:

```
var db []DATA

func addToDB(key, value string) {
    db = append(db, DATA{Key: key, Value: value})
}

func main() {
    addToDB("key1", "value1")
    addToDB("key2", "value2")
    addToDB("key3", "value3")

    saveDbAsMap(db)
}
```

Output in db.json:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

Comment: it need to take input from the user, and then later it need to save inside the `db.json` file, at now using your code, it just delete everything in the file and re-enter the last key and value pair

Comment: JSON is a structured format, so it is not possible to do an "append" to a json file.
As an option, you can store all the DB data as a `map[string]interface{}` instead of `[]DATA`, so you don't have to do a conversion.

Comment: The logic would be: read everything from the "db.json", add new values as users input them, then save the DB back to the json file.

Comment: Okay... I was thinking to edit code a little bit.
the time we declared the `db` array, we can read the file there too? and can get all the previous entry saved inside(db.json) to the array, after that we will add the new one(key and pair) again inside the `db.json` file, make sense? will it work?